# Calculating Wilson coefficients quickly

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

I am currently trying to compute the Wilson coefficients for the different amplitudes in scalar field theories, where these are the coefficients $\mathcal{W}_{pq}$ defined by $$ \mathcal{M}(s,t) = \sum_{p,q} \mathcal{W}_{pq} x^p y^q $$ where $x$ and $y$ are crossing symmetric variables, defined as $$ s_1s_2 + s_2s_3+s_3s_1 = -x $$ $$ s_1 s_2 s_3 = -y $$ with $s_1 = s - 4m^2/3$, $s_2 = t - 4m^2/3 $ and $s_3 = u - 4m^2/3$ and $s,t,u$ are the usual Mandelstam variables.
Right now, I am naively trying to solve $s_1,s_2,s_3$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, substitute in the expression for $\mathcal{M}(s_1,s_2)$ and then finding out the (p,q)-th coefficient of the series. But that is, as you would no doubt appreciate, a very slow algorithm, even for Mathematica, although I get results within 5 minutes for every coefficient. Still, I would like to know of any methods that can accelerate the procedure.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the theory of symmetric polynomials. In particular the expressions you wrote down are so called elementary symmetric polynomials in $s_i$. There are many known identities satisfied by symmetric polynomials, perhaps some may be of use.

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As $s+t+u=4m^2$, your $s_i$ also satisfy $s_1+s_2+s_3=0$.  So, using the definition of $x$, $y$ and
$$
(\sigma-s_1)(\sigma-s_2)(\sigma-s_3) = \sigma^3 -(s_1+s_2+s_3)\sigma^2 +(s_1s_2+s_2s_3+s_1s_3)\sigma- s_1s_2s_3
$$
you see that  they are the roots of the cubic equation
$$
\sigma^3 - x\sigma +y=0.
$$
The solutions are given explicitly by [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation) or by a trigonometric formula that is lower down in the Wikipedia article. Hope this helps.

So you have a symmetric function and want to expand it in terms of the elementary symmetric functions $x$ and $y$?  The only systematic thing I can think of to use their orthogonality to expand it in terms of [Schur polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial), and then use the second Jacobi-Trudi formula to expand the Schur polynomials  in the elementary symmetric functions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. But I am actually using Mathematica to compute the roots, which it can do pretty easily, and then substitute it in $\mathcal{M}$. The trouble arises when I'm trying to compute the series coefficients of this (algebraically messy) $\mathcal{M}$ which is when Mathematica struggles a lot.